# set configuration constants depending on environment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to define a constant (like the admin-email-adress) depending on the environment. What is the easiest way to do this?

I'd like something like that, in development.rb (or test or production.rb):

```
ADMIN_EMAIL = "foo@bar.com"
```

And be able to access it by calling something like

```
ADMIN_EMAIL
```

Is there an easy way or do I have to do something like creating a module and initialize it and stuff (and in case you're wondering if I have any idea about this, unfortunately: I don't)

> It works this way, but one has to
>   restart the server, for the constants
>   to take effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `config/environments/`, there are some configuration files that get executed based on what environment you're currently in. Try defining a constant in one of those.

Comment: Ah, OK, I was trying to do that, but didn't realize I had to restart the server, so it would get initialized.